# Avoid ask others permission if one is not granted with RxPermissions

Tags: android, rx-android, rxpermissions

I want to avoid ask others permission if the user not grant one.

For example: I ask for read/write external storage and camera, if the user deny the first, the library ask for camera permission, camera permission is redundant in this case.

```
RxPermissions.getInstance(getActivity()).request(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                .subscribe(granted -> {
                    if (granted) {
                       dispatchCamera();
                    } else {
                        showError();
                    }
                });
```

I think I could use requestEach, but I dont know how stop to emit items if one permission is not granted and also I cant obtain the final result, if the user grant all permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose your problem was solved, but I gonna place answer, for somebody else, who get into same trouble.

All you need is [**takeUntil**](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takeuntil.html) or [**takeWhile**](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takewhile.html) operator with **requestEach**(depends what stream behaviour you want). **TakeUntil** unsubscribe you from stream, and bring you only events with *granted permissions* and one of *permission denied* inclusive.If you want get only *permission granted* events without any of them == denied, pls use **takeWhile** opertator. 
Just maybe you would have to experement with this code a while, cause I didnt use this library yet, and maybe something would behave not exactly as you want.

So code might be like this:

```
 RxPermissions
      .getInstance(getActivity())
      .requestEach(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
         Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
         Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
      .takeWhile(permission -> permission.granted)
      //or use take untill if you want to get permission.granted == false event
      //.takeUntil(permission -> !permission.granted)
      .subscribe(granted -> {
        if (granted) {
           dispatchCamera();
        } else {
           showError();
        }
      });
```

Comment: Thanks! Better late than never!